# Programmatically create a whole Drupal site

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am going to start a new project and I would like to avoid the tedious tasks necessary to recreate and populate a site with all the custom content, modules and functionality.

My idea is to create PHP scripts (similar to the installation scripts in the `profile` folder) to populate users, content, menus, views, etc. In this way you can execute the scripts and rebuild the whole site from scratch.

Do you know any tool/documentation to do this?

Comment: populate with random data? or your own ?

Comment: My own data, but also my own modules, content types, themes, etc.

Comment: then you have to read about drupal profiles, which in turn is very similar to building modules. Also you can try looking into Drush..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at [`drush make`](http://www.drush.org/docs/make.txt), which is part of the very helpful [`drush`](http://drupal.org/project/drush) command line shell & scripting interface for Drupal.

You can generate a starting makefile from an existing Drupal installation using:

```
 drush make-generate /path/to/make-file.make
```

.. and then tweak the configuration as needed, including custom file/module downloads.

Comment: [Drushmake.me](http://drushmake.me/) is also a good tool to create drush makefile.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always build new profile that will help you build new web-sites.
Please look at [How to Write a Drupal 7 Installation Profile](http://drupal.org/node/1022020). Its simular like building new module (documented).

For our needs in the company, we've build 2 type of profile installation but sometimes it was more worth to copy existing site and install it on new domain. But I assume that our needs are different then yours.